# Why does a '=' scope binding behave different from a $watch?

Tags: angularjs

What is, from the $digest loop's point of view, the difference between a directive with

```
scope:{foo:'='}
```

and one with

```
scope:{},
controller:function($scope, $attrs}{
    $scope.$watch($attrs.foo, function(foodata){$scope.foo=foodata});
}
```

?

While most of the time these have the same result on a directive with, say `template='foo={{foo}}`, and while both converge when attribute values like `{x:1,y:2}` (which are never `===` in different evaluations), the former even converges on `{x:1,y:number}` (where `number` is defined on the scope from outside to be `2`), while the latter ends up in a "`10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`" loop.

Obviously they have different behavior, but how can even the latter be made to converge? (Simply using the former form helps, but doesn't work with `scope:true`.)

Note that up to a point between 1.2.0 and 1.2.21, such expressions never converged, even if they were completely "static" and evaluated through a `'='` scope.

A complete example can be found on http://plnkr.co/edit/mOhhQVPs4XqcTQ3TNMfI?p=preview .

Answer (score 0):

scope: {}. means isolate scope, you can access scope.$parent to get parent scope but you don't get inherited properties through the prototype chain.

scope: true. means child scope, you can access scope.$parent to get parent scope and also you get inherited properties through the prototype chain.

Regarding your problem, it seems to be related to this [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/43072e3812e32b89b97ad03144577cba50d4b776). If you would like it to behave the same you should add object equality checking to your $watch:

```
  $scope.$watch($attrs.foo, function(foodata) {
    $scope.foo=foodata;
  }, true);
```